# Month of day with sequence in one for loop or range-v3 lib

Tags: c++, range, c++20, range-v3

I try to take month of day with sequence like this: for january it will print 1 with 31 time, in february will print 2 with 28 time etc.

```cpp
std::vector<int> list = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

int count = 0;
for(int k = 0; k < 12; k++){
   for(int i = 0; i < list[k]; i++)
       cout << count + 1;
   count++;
}
```

list keep the month's total days.

I can do with this for loops but I want to do in 1 loop or range-v3 lib. In range-v3 lib I try to use accumulate function but I cannot do.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/for_each) and [`fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fill_n).

```
std::ranges::for_each(list, [count = 0](int i) mutable { std::ranges::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "), i, ++count); });
```

Answer (score 1):

With range-v3, you might do:

```
std::array<int, 12> days{ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

auto r = days | ranges::view::transform([count = 0](int n) mutable
                {
                    return ranges::view::ints(1, 1 + n)
                         | ranges::view::transform([count = ++count](int){ return count; });
                })
              | ranges::view::join;

for (auto e : r) 
    std::cout << e << ' ';
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f418748c18b60ce)

but

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
   for (int j = 0; j != days[i]; ++j) {
       std::cout << i + 1;
   }
}
```

seems clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you're looking for is `flat_map`. Which range-v3 cleverly hides under the name `for_each`.

Basically, we have `transform` (what some other languages call `map`) - this takes a range of `T` and a function `T -> U` and produces a range of `U`. It's a 1-1 mapping.

We can generalize this to an algorithm that takes a range of `T` and a function `T -> range_of<U>` and produces a range of `U`. Whereas `transform` by itself would have produced a range of range of `U`, we're flattening the result. Hence, `flat_map`.

In range-v3, this looks like:

```cpp
views::iota(0u, days_in_month.size())
   | views::for_each([&](int month){
         return views::repeat_n(month+1, days_in_month[month])
     })
```

or

```cpp
views::enumerate(days_in_month)
   | views::for_each([](auto e){
        auto [idx, days] = e;
        return views::repeat_n(idx+1, days);
     })
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MqjGjx).